# AVCaptureDevice on macOS

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avcapturedevice, macos-high-sierra

Is it possible to display a camera feed in a macOS app? I'm basically trying to capture images frame by frame from a camera feed. I know how to do this in iOS, but for some reasons, on macOS, I can't seem to find any `AVCaptureDevice` for video.

```
let x = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
```

// When I print x, I only see the Microphone as the only capture device. No reference to video/camera whatsoever

```
guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else{ return }
```

Comment: I would love to help. Could you please edit your question to make it a little more clear as to what you're trying to accomplish? I am a tad confused and would like some elaboration.

Comment: Hi Colton, what can I elaborate on? `AVCaptureDevice.devices()` returns a capture device object for video on iOS, but not on macOS. Why?

Comment: @Colton only on iOS

Comment: @7ball please take a look at my answer I hope this helps.

Comment: I have corrected my answer

Comment: @7ball have you solved it?

Answer (score 23):

I had the exact same issue, AVCaptureDevice.devices() only returned one entry, a microphone. Solution for me was to turn on the Camera checkbox in Project:Capabilities:App Sandbox. Output after I set the Camera checkbox...

```
▿ 2 elements
  - 0 : <AVCaptureHALDevice: 0x60c0000e4980 [Built-in Microphone][AppleHDAEngineInput:1B,0,1,0:1]>
  - 1 : <AVCaptureDALDevice: 0x101302b10 [FaceTime HD Camera][CC245055EWDF6VVDY]>
```

Comment: Great, I need to check camera in Capabilities and for safety not to crash when running on device, add "Privacy - Camera Usage Description" in Info.plist file for usage description of camera.

Comment: Now available on macOS 10.15+ Is my answer — “this should be the accepted answer now.” – Kristóf Zelei Stated under my answer.

Answer (score -2):

To find available capture devices use `AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession` as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice.discoverysession)

Then use the `default(_:for:position:)` method to return a default device for the specified media type as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/2361508-default)

Comment: DiscoverySession is only available on iOS

Comment: Now available on macOS 10.15+, this should be the accepted answer now.